# Add Watermark to PowerPoint Slide from Excel

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to add a watermark to a PowerPoint slide from Excel with VBA and don't know where to start. I have searched on Google and found nothing. There is one question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013871/in-powerpoint-2010-2013-how-to-keep-watermark-always-on-top-using-vba) that helped a little but I couldn't follow it. I am wondering if someone could refer me to somewhere or point me in the right direction? Again, I just want to add a watermark to one of the slides in Master View. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your watermark? An image/shape?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for replying. My watermark is a picture. I am storing the picture in a `VeryHidden` worksheet in Excel. I want to put a textbox in a blank slide in slide master and format the shape with `picture or text fill`.

Comment: Got it - do you have any code already that would clarify the question/reduce the effort involved in answering it satisfactorily? I.e. if you're working with PowerPoint from Excel I assume you've already have the PowerPoint instance and presentation, you have your sheet name, etc.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, I already have the PowerPoint application/presentation instantiated. I just need the above portion. I can post that code if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a slide in Master View, you can work with the [`CustomLayouts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/customlayouts-object-powerpoint) collection.

Note that you'll have to refer to a specific `CustomLayout` by its index, and not its `Name`, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147643/how-to-apply-particular-layout-in-powerpoint-using-vba) points out.

This example code

- creates or gets a PowerPoint instance
- creates a new `Presentation`
- copies `Picture 1` and pastes it in the `Shapes` collection of the first `CustomLayout`, which for me is the Title Slide Layout.

I assume from here you can modify its size/position or make any other desired changes.

```
Sub AddWatermark()
    Dim wmark As Shape: Set wmark = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 1")
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set PPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If PPT Is Nothing Then
        Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
    
    PPT.Visible = True
    Set pres = PPT.Presentations.Add
    
    wmark.Copy
    pres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1).Shapes.Paste
    
End Sub
```

---

*My Original Watermark*

[image: My Original Watermark]

---

*Title Slide Layout showing applied watermark*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It gets me almost the entire way there. I just need it in a textbox now to make it transparent.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to add to a textbox or rectangle from the clipboard?

Comment: I do not - but can you have the text box or rectangle in your excel file to begin with?

Comment: I ended up storing the pictures on a SharePoint site and using the `UserPicture` method. It worked perfectly. Your code gave me what I needed. It was the `SlideMaster.CustomLayouts` portion I didn't understand and needed. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brian no problem, glad to help.